# Roll up ids and time series for forecasting - efficient method

Tags: python, r, pandas

I have a table like below

```
id time
1 2017-11-01 2:00:00
1 2017-11-01 2:00:20
1 2017-11-01 2:00:40
1 2017-11-01 2:01:00
.
.
.
123 2017-12-21 11:59:59
```

I want to find total time per id per day. What is an effective method of doing this in R/Python?

Ideally get something like

```
id date minutes
1 2017-11-01 25
1 2017-11-01 22
.
.
```

I do not want to do this using a nested for loop. Any better way to so it?

I was thinking using apply like below using a list of DFs for each ID

```
lapply(names(myDF), function(x) {aggregateTime())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python you could use `groupby.first` and [`groupby.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) in something like:

```
groupby = ('id', pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='d'))
begin = df.groupby(groupby ).first().astype('datetime64[ns]')
end = df.groupby(groupby ).last().astype('datetime64[ns]')
diff = (end - begin)['time'] 
diff = ((end - begin)['time'] / pd.Timedelta('1M')).round() # if you want it in minutes
```

`diff` can be a `Series` of `Timedelta` or a series of minuts, depending on what you want

## variation

```
def time_diff(group):
    diff = group['time'].max()- group['time'].min()
    return round(diff / pd.Timedelta('1M'))
df.groupby(groupby).apply(time_diff)
```